# Removing or Hiding a specific(only one) datatable column depending on media query size

Tags: datatable

I have a responsive datatable just like in this example
https://editor.datatables.net/examples/extensions/responsive.html
but one of my column contains links which means when my datatable collapse and I click the expand button, the link column extends and destroys the responsiveness of my webpage (table should be alligned with the green jumbotron on top)

[image]

i tried hiding the link column on a specific media query through
adding a classname in th and in target [4] (4 is the number of column link) then add a css display none but it only hides the text not the whole column

```
@media (max-width: 700px) {
.hide {
display:none;
}
<th class="hide" width="30%">Link</th>

"targets": [4],
"className": "hide",
}
```

i also tried

```
@media (max-width: 700px) {
    table th, table td{
       display:none;
    }
table th:nth-child(1), table th:nth-child(2), table th:nth-child(3), table th:nth-child(5), table th:nth-child(6), 
    table td:nth-child(1), table td:nth-child(2),table td:nth-child(3),  table td:nth-child(5), table td:nth-child(6){
        display:table-cell;
    }
```

and it still does not work

Do you have any idea on how to hide a column in a specific media query size. Other approach are also welcome the only thing i want is for the datatable to be responsive all the time. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solve by adding classname and css to td

```
 "columnDefs": [{
"targets": [4],
'createdCell':  function (td) {
$(td).addClass('myclass');
}
}]

<th class="myclass" width="30%">Link</th>

@media (max-width: 700px) {
.myclass {
display:none!important;
}
}
```